# Create a column with random decimal values

Tags: r, random, decimal

Just trying to create a column with random decimal points between 0.001 and 0.009 
I'm using the code:

`data$newrow <- sample(0.001:0.009,replace=T, nrow(data))`

but seems to only produce a column with 0.001.

`summary(data$newrow) 
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.001   0.001   0.001   0.001   0.001   0.001`

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the results of `0.001:0.009` - you're essentially wanting to sample from a uniform distribution - `runif(100,0.001,0.009)`

Comment: You need `seq` here i.e. `seq(0.001, 0.009, by = 0.001)`

Comment: yes, `data$newrow <- sample(seq(0.001, 0.009, by = 0.001),replace=T, nrow(data))` works! Thank you